# Problem with bash script

Tags: bash, sorting, rsync

I'm using this bash script:

```
for a in `sort -u $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves`; do
        rsync -e ssh -a "${HADOOP_HOME}/conf" ${a}:"${HADOOP_HOME}"
done
for a in `sort -u $HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers`; do
        rsync -e ssh -a "${HBASE_HOME}/conf" ${a}:"${HBASE_HOME}"
done
```

When I call this script directly from shell, there are no problems and it works fine. But when I call this script from another script, although the script does its job, I get this message at the end:

```
sort: open failed: /conf/slaves: No such file or directory
sort: open failed: /conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
```

I have set $HADOOP_HOME and $HBASE_HOME in /etc/profile and the script does the job right. But I don't understand why it gives this message in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you *sure* it's doing it right? When you call this script from the shell it is acting as an **interactive** shell which reads and sources `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` if it exists.  When you call it from another script it is running as **non-interactive** and wont source those files.  If you want a non-interactive shell to source a file you can do this by setting the `BASH_ENV` environment variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

export BASH_ENV=/etc/profile
./call/to/your/HADOOP/script.sh
```

Comment: I confirmed the problem to be this, but exporting BASH_ENV still doesn't solve it..

Comment: solved now.. I was using sh ./call/to/your/HADOOP/script.sh, so it was creating a new shell. When I call it as simply ./call/to/your/HADOOP/script.sh, it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything points to those variables *not* being defined when your script runs.

You should ensure that they *are* set for your script. Before the first loop, place the line:

```
echo "[${HADOOP_HOME}] [${HBASE_HOME}]"
```

and make sure that doesn't output `"[] []"` (or even one `"[]"`).

Additionally, put a `set +x` line at the top of the script - this will output lines before executing them and you can see what's being done.

Keep in mind that some shells don't pass on environment variables to subshells unless you explicitly export them (setting them is not enough).

Comment: No, I haven't exported explicitly but the script works fine individually and also when called from other scripts. Just that it gives this warning message which I can't seem to get rid of.

Comment: this helped to debug the issue.. thanks! when called directly, it does print it right, but when accessed from another script, it prints blank..